# Bootstrap carousel stretched image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with the size of my carousel image slider using bootstrap.

I tried changing the height of the images using inline css but the images still are stretched.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img style="min-height: 250px;" class="d-block w-100" src="images/hikvision.png" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img style="min-height: 250px;" class="d-block w-100" src="images/hikvision_2.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100 h-25" src="images/hikvision_3.png" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your code and no files. And specify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The files are in the google drive link I shared. Also I am trying to keep the image at the 200px size since I don't want it to take up the whole height of the page.

Comment: You've told the images to be a minimum of 250 pixels in height; perhaps you should set this to 200px (and also a max-height:200px; value too)

Comment: Because you are new here I did your job and added the code to show what I mean. This way nobody needs to download foreign files and I corrected your html btw. you forgot to close the <head> and forgot to begin the <body>

Comment: I did that but the actual size of the image is 200px but I dont think I need to specify the styles since it is at the right size. Also when I do as you suggest the images shrinks and becomes distorted(aspect ratio is lost).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the lack of the images (because they are stored locally on your machine) I can see that you're using min-height.

> The min-height property defines the minimum height of an element.
>   If the content is smaller than the minimum height, the minimum height will be applied.
>   If the content is larger than the minimum height, the min-height property has no effect.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)
Use [max-]height and you might get what you want.